# mysql 8 recover tables only from .ibd files

Tags: mysql-8.0

My database files are corrupted somehow!!

I have got only the .ibd (eg: customers.ibd) files of the table names in the MySql data directory, there is no other file extension of the table is available (eg: .frm or .myd).

Is there any ways to recover the data of the database??

Comment: my sql server has crashed :((  and i get this .ibd files from this path: "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data"

Comment: Updated link for resource in comment by @Progman: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-enterprise-backup-3.11-en/partial.restoring.single.html

Comment: The resource requires that mysql is working and you have access to your database. It uses the existing table and simply replaces the data.

Comment: In my case, mysql just stopped working. Mysql wouldn't start, so I couldn't access the database, and I couldn't uninstall or reinstall mysql. This prevented me from retrieving the table structure from mysql. The table structure must be exact for the mentioned process to work. Thankfully, I had a copy of the table structure, so I created a new virtual machine, transferred the ibd file, installed mysql, created the table, followed a similar set of instructions, and I was able to recover the database.

Comment: It might be helpful to know that mysql stopped using fpm files in version 8.0.  Instead, the information is now stored using a different format inside of the ibd file. There are plenty of older solutions that require a fpm file, but none of those will work for version 8.0 and higher.

Comment: I was lucky that I had the table structure saved, but I'm still trying to find a way to recover the complete table structure to help anyone who isn't as lucky. There is a way to recover most of the table structure, but not enough to recreate the exact table. https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/12/07/mysql-8-frm-drop-how-to-recover-table-ddl/

Comment: If you need to recover the data, please contact me, and I can help you recover the data. (mysql 8, only ibd files)